# Passing state variables from Child To Parent using React

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit

I feel like there is an easier way to do all this. I am trying to pass all of the `state` variables from `Child` to `Parent` after the user has clicked the `Submit button`. Could somebody please point out what I am doing wrong?

**AddSeanceForm.js** (Child)

```
class AddSeanceForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(...args) {
       super(...args);
        this.state = {
           devices: "",
           interval: ""
        };
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
            <form onSubmit={(event, devices, interval) => this.props.handleSubmit(event, this.state.devices, this.state.interval)}>
            ...)
```

**SeanceManager.js** (Parent)

```
handleSubmit = (event, devices, interval) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(devices, interval)
    ...
};
```

This solution works, but I am planning to make more variables and this does not seem optimal.

Comment: Hi kataroty! Just wrote you an answer, let me know if that's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to define the event handler inside the Parent component and pass it down as a prop to the Child. That event handler will be bound to your Parent component's execution context. Also, in your parent component, you can initiate an empty state-variable, then simply spread {...obj} the data from the Child component into it when you execute the event-handler.

Heres the code sandbox too if you need it: https://codesandbox.io/s/zxl2owp2np

**Parent:**

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  updateState = obj => {
    this.setState({ ...obj }, () => console.log(this.state));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Child updateParent={this.updateState} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child:**

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    age: 0
  };

  handleOnSubmit = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const childState = this.state;
    this.props.updateParent(childState);
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
        <input
          name="name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
        />
        <input
          name="age"
          value={this.state.age}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, It does work indeed this way but I was looking for something even simpler. But this will do. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @kataroty! Glad this helped! I would be excited to find an even simpler solution to this problem! I think this will work fine just for our current scaling needs.